# @Resource annotation producing NPE

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, spring-ws

I "inherited" a large Spring application with a spring-ws service in it.

The service is the typical Spring-WS code:

```
package service;

@Endpoint
public class ServiceEndpoint {
    @Resource EntityDao entityDao;

    @PayloadRoot(localPart=...)
    @ResponsePayload
    public ResponseWrapperClass getServiceMethod(@RequestPayload RequestWrapperClass request) {
        return new ResponseProcessorClass(request).generateResponse();
    }
}
```

The service is massive, and the entityDao injected with the @Resource annotation is used widely in the class.

Because the specific method I'm working on is a bit complex, I have encapsulated it in a separate class in a subpackage.

The ResponseProcessorClass looks like this:

```
package service.business;
@Component
public class ResponseProcessorClass {
    @Resource EntityDao entityDao;

    public ResponseWrapperClass generateResponse() {
        entityDao.getSomeData(); //encapsulates hibernate logic -> Null Pointer Exception
    }
}
```

As you can see by my comments above, I get a Null Pointer Exception when using the @Resource annotation in my new class.

I haven't used this annotation before, but for what I understood from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncjk.html) the type should be inferred and injected. I could not find any configuration in any XML file for it either.

Could anyone tell me why am I getting the NPE?

Comment: Spring managed beans. Spring can only autowire beans it manages.

Comment: I understand that. The fact is that this works in the existing codebase. I have simply taken the logic from the @Endpoint class and moved it to a separate package.

Comment: This is the problem: `return new  ResponseProcessorClass(request).generateResponse();`

Comment: Thanks. But can't understand why this is the problem and what should I do instead.

Comment: You're expecting Spring to inject an `EntityDao` bean when you are the one creating the object. Spring can only inject beans it controls/manages. Can you show your full `ResponseProcessorClass` class?

Comment: awesome. that's solved my problem. you should post the answer so I could accept it. I just replaced the new ResponseProcessorClass with another object that I am injecting with the @Resource annotation as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring can only inject Spring managed beans into Spring managed beans. Therefore, if you create the object yourself, Spring can't do anything about it. This

```
return new ResponseProcessorClass(request).generateResponse();
```

is the problem. You are expecting Spring to inject a field of the `ResponseProcessorClass` object *you* created.

Try injecting a prototype bean instead of creating it yourself. This depends on your `ResponseProcessorClass` class.